# Javascript Alternative to Animation-Iteration-Count as Infinite

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a firework animation via JavaScript. I have invoked CSS3 animations with jQuery using an iteration count of `1`, but with the `webkitAnimationEnd` event -- which doesn't trigger when you use a pure CSS3 iteration count of infinite -- so I feel it would be more appropriate to use a loop.

I'm choosing JavaScript because I need to play the event sequentially but with more control than CSS3 offers.

Example: http://codepen.io/tusharsaurabh/pen/YpqOZB

---

Animation doesn't get initiated when I execute it in a loop. In one another Stack Overflow post, someone mentioned re-generating the HTML content -- which I did, and the line going upwards is getting triggered, though the rest of the animation.

How do I make all my animations run in a loop with pure JavaScript/jQuery (no CSS3)?

```
var rocket = document.getElementById('shooting'),

    // Circles
    circle1 = document.getElementById('circle-1'),
    circle2 = document.getElementById('circle-2'),
    circle3 = document.getElementById('circle-3'),
    circle4 = document.getElementById('circle-4'),

    // Timer
    shootingTimer = null;

// Listen for webkitAnimationEnd
rocket.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", animation_end_rocket);
circle1.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", animation_end_circle);
circle2.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", animation_end_circle);
circle3.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", animation_end_circle);
circle4.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", animation_end_circle);

function animation_end_rocket() {
  $('#circle-1').css('display', 'block');
  $('#circle-1').css('animation', 'zoom1 0.1s 1');
}

function animation_end_circle1() {
  $('#circle-1').css('display', 'none');
  $('#circle-2').css('display', 'block');
  $('#circle-2').css('animation', 'zoom1 0.1s 1');
}

function animation_end_circle2() {
  $('#circle-2').css('display', 'none');
  $('#circle-3').css('display', 'block');
  $('#circle-3').css('animation', 'zoom1 0.1s 1');

}

function animation_end_circle3() {
  $('#circle-3').css('display', 'none');
  $('#circle-4').css('display', 'block');
  $('#circle-4').css('animation', 'zoom1 0.1s 1');

}

function animation_end_circle4() {
  $('#circle-4').css('display', 'none');
}

function shoot() {

    var container = document.getElementById('main'),
        content = container.innerHTML;

        container.innerHTML = content;

        $("#shooting").css("animation", 1000);
}

shootingTimer = = setInterval(shoot, 100);
```

Comment: Are you using this as a test of **webkitAnimationEnd**, or is the fireworks the ultimate objective?

Comment: @JonSG Fireworks is ultimate objective.